# std::cin, ввод в строковую константу

Tags: c++

Что значит:

1. `cin` позволяет читать данные с терминала пользователя,
2. `cout` позволяет выводить данные на терминал пользователя.

Есть 2 фрагмента кода:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin >> "Hello, world!" >> endl;
    return 0;
}
```

и

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Все же не понял их отличие, оба в терминале выводят текст `Hello, world!`

Comment: Лично у меня ошибка компиляции

Comment: Дополнил код (библиотека+пространство имен)

Comment: так я так и делал

Comment: [Ошибка компиляции](http://ideone.com/JxgwsH)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Код в примере некорректный. У меня пишет следующее:

```
 1.cc:7:12: note:   cannot convert ‘"Hello, world!"’ (type ‘const char [14]’) to type ‘unsigned char
```

И это вполне логично, т.к. в C++ строковые литералы есть константы, т.е. их нельзя изменять, а `std::cin` оператором `>>` изменяет свой первый аргумент. Можно посмотреть сигнатуру `std::istream::operator>>` (а `cin` именно типа `istream`) в стандартной библиотеке и `const` там и в помине нет... Т.е. фактически нет такой ф-ции, которая Вам годится. Можно ее теоретически наколдовать путем перезагрузки, но нужно ли?

Более того - `cin>>"abc"` и не может выводить строку `abc` на экран, т.к. у него все перегруженные варианты оператора `>>` занимаются только вводом данных.

Условно я Ваш код спас следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

istream& operator>> (istream& a , const char *val)
{
    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. тупо перегрузил оператор >> для const char*.